# Is a slice category over a set a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$?

Tags: category-theory

In programming, one can interpret data types as sets, and functions as set morphisms. Hence, we embed the programming language within $\mathbf{Set}$ in order to interpret code within category theory. Now, this lead me to a question regarding slice categories. In want to define a special type $\mathcal M$ where the objects are tuples $(A,\theta_A)$ such that $\theta_A:A\to M$. In other words, I have a slice category over $M$, i.e. $\mathbf{Set}/M$.

My question is whether this slice category can be interpreted as a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$, and if this is not always true, I was wondering if there was a condition on whether this became true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can:
There is a natural isomorphism
$$
\mathbf{Set}/M \to \prod_M\mathbf{Set}, \quad [\theta\colon A\to M]\mapsto (\theta^{-1}(m))_m.
$$
This is a functor, because morphisms in the slice category are given by morphisms *over $M$*, so they restrict to maps on fibers.

The latter category has a functor into $\mathbf{Set}$, sending $(A_m)_m$ to $\prod_M A_m$.

Edit:
As Mark Kamsma has correctly pointed out, there are strong reasons to prefer the functor sending $(A_m)_m$ to $\coprod_m A_m$. Additionally, this yields a faithful functor.

However, it is not a *full* subcategory, and I don't have an argument why that should or shouldn't be possible.

Comment: You can make your "convenient functor" take $(A_m)_{m \in M}$ to $\coprod_{m \in M} A_m$. Then it will be full and faithful. In other words: pairs $(A, \theta_A)$ are essentially just $M$-indexed families of sets, which are essentially just $M$-fold disjoint unions of sets.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I agree that your and my functor are faithful. I fail to see how your functor is full, fibres are still preserved. For example: The final element $\mathrm{id}_M$ is sent to $\bigcup \{m\}$, which is not final in $\mathbf{Set}$ when $|M|\neq 1$, so there will be missing morphisms to this object.

Comment: Ah of course, you are right. You should still use the disjoint union though, rather than the product: what if one of the $A_m$ is empty? Though I suppose that is not an immediate issue, it does lose more information than necessary.

Comment: Also, it is an issue for faithfulness of your functor. Consider $M = 2  = \{0,1\}$. Take $A_0 = \{a\}, A_2 = \emptyset$ and $B_0 = \{b_1, b_2\}, B_2 = \emptyset$. Then there are two morphisms $(A_0, A_1) \to (B_0, B_1)$ while there is only the empty function $A_0 \times A_1 \to B_0 \times B_1$.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have edited the post to include your comments.